# How to " RESET to DEFAULT " colors of text editor in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans

I want to see Netbeans look as like Photoshop CS6 , Visual studio type. So

1. Installed a dark theme and
2. I changed some option and code elements colours for my satisfaction.

And I forgot what the changes I did

3. I tried all the colours combination  and it became worse
4. Even Reinstall also not helped me

I had searched a lot to make it default

My Problem (image) is  [image: this]:

Comment: To reset all configurations, you don't re-install, you delete the "userdir" where all configurations are stored. See the NetBeans FAQ: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ#Configuration

Comment: So if deleting of already stored ... like "cache" .. will helps..

then i think i can copy the userdir file from friend's device to mine...  i will try in that way .. thanks for your support dude ..>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to `Tools\Options\Fonts & Colors` and click on the `Restore` button.

The help page says:

> Click Restore to restore the selected profile to the default settings.

Comment: Here showing the dropdown list, so you can select NetBeans option

Answer (score 5):

You should go to tools>options>fonts & colors then set the profile to  netbeans.
that will restore the colors to default.

Answer (score 4):

In Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors, change Profile from Norway Today to NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

Alt + Shift + F does the wonder. Incidentally, I used to get this issue too frequently and I noticed that this appears / disappears every time I try the shortcut key for code format (Alt + Shift + F)

Answer (score 0):

**i have a same problem and i finally i found a solution**

create a **new instance** of net beans so when you create a new instance the newer instance will contain default settings now if you don't want older instance of net beans delete the older one and start using new one.

it will work 100%

to create a new instance this web site will help you...

http://netbeanside61.blogspot.in/2008/12/opening-multiple-netbeans-ide-instances.html [image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had changed the theme as well as how all my formatting was done. To get it back to default I changed the Netbeans.conf file and restarted the application. The file was found here.

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\etc
```