# Java Netbeans - Errors not showing up

Tags: java, netbeans-8

My Netbeans is not showing up errors in the editor. It's showing errors in the bottom bar. I have no idea how to resolve it.

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem a lot, I am usually able to fix it by hitting the save all button, but in the code you showed me it doesn't look like there is any errors.

You could also try to reset your settings:
https://core.netbeans.org/proposals/reset-settings-ui-spec.html

There is also a link here that also explains how to reset:
[How to " RESET to DEFAULT " colors of text editor in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742533/how-to-reset-to-default-colors-of-text-editor-in-netbeans)

Comment: If you see to the very bottom of the page,errors are showing there

Comment: try going into the settings here and see if you can find the setting                             Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Syntax

Comment: You might have accidentally turned it off

Comment: No ,everything seems fine there .

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after changing the setting `Preferred look and feel` under `Tools/Options/Appearance/Look and Feel`

Toggling this setting between a different option and my preferred option fixed the issue somehow...